# Is there a way to set "local-port" curl option in PHP?

Tags: php, curl

I would like to explicitly define the source port range curl should use for the connections.
In curl docs this option would be local-port, but I can't find any PHP documentation relating to the setup of this curl option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a [comment in the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php#91978):

> Seems like some options not mentioned on this page, but listed on http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_setopt.html is actually supported.

According to the [libcurl docs](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_LOCALPORT.html), `CURLOPT_LOCALPORT` is what you're looking for.  Hopefully that's defined in PHP.  If it isn't, you can try using the value `139` [according to the source](https://github.com/bagder/curl/blob/master/include/curl/curl.h#L1318).

Comment: yes, it seems the ide recognizes the constant. The numbers are 139 and 140 . The alst one is for a range of ports. Testing it now.

Comment: Some tests seem not to work. I don't really think php is taking this option into consideration. But var_dumping the consntants seem to output the proper option int codes. I will test more.

Comment: @Geo Hmm, have you tried just using the numeric value directly?

Comment: It seems to work I guess, but I still get problems with port firewalls over tcp. I will have to check further all the curl process flow. Accepted

Comment: @Geo No reasonable firewall configuration disallows client ports when connecting to a remote HTTP server.  You either have a special situation, or your problem is elsewhere.  I recommend using a packet sniffer (such as Wireshark) to see what's happening over the wire.

Comment: It is 100% from the firewall. Everytime I deny any usage of protocols besides TCP , the curl is not working. What I am guessing is that cURL is using ICMP to ping the remote address/port before establishing a tcp connection. When I allow any input/output/protocol curl seems to work properly. Too bad curl does not show a full process flow with the -V option.

Comment: @Geo cURL doesn't ping the host before connecting.  You can prove this for yourself with a packet sniffer.